# In Delphi is there a way to backup and restore a database using FireDAC

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is there a way to backup and restore a database using FireDAC?

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin and connecting to MSSQL Server.  Ideally it would backup all the interesting attributes of the database (records, indexes etc..), but a solution that just does a backup and restore of the data would be fine (I can recreate all the meta-data prior to restoring).

Comment: Isn't it a database adminstration task, handled at IT level? Why should it be done in Delphi? Backups are usually done on the actual Server itself. Pumping all data to a DB client will consume a lot of resources, for almost no benefit. If you expect something lighter, switch to alternatives, e.g. SQLite3 with a client/server REST layer: it is easy to backup such databases - you just have to copy the file, or use its Backup API.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, one of my customers distributes MSSQL Express with every machine delivered. While other clients access this server from different machines there is also a master/server application running on the same system as SQL Server. It would be nice to implement the backup and restore mechanisms directly inside this application. Currently we solve this by executing external applications with less control over the process. 
BTW, switching to another database is no option here.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez It's desktop software, most users will have the server (express) running on their machine (single user or small network install), while others will connect to a proper server (corporate install).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confess I'm a bit puzzled by your q because the answer seems a bit too easy, namely
use FireDAC's `TDFConnection` to execute SqlServer TransactSql scripts to back up and restore the database.  I hope you don't regard that as cheating ;)

Example project code

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
    btnBackUp: TButton;
    btnRestore: TButton;
    FDMetaInfoQuery1: TFDMetaInfoQuery;
    FDPhysMSSQLDriverLink1: TFDPhysMSSQLDriverLink;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;  //  connected to DataSource1
    DataSource1: TDataSource;  // connected to FDMetaInfoQuery1
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure btnBackUpClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnRestoreClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  [...]

const
  scBackUpPath = 'D:\MSSql2014\Backup\';
  scBackupExtn = '.Bak';

procedure TForm1.Log(const Msg : String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Msg);
end;

function TForm1.DatabaseName: String;
begin
  Result := FDMetaInfoQuery1.FieldByName('Catalog_Name').AsString;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDMetaInfoQuery1.MetaInfoKind := mkCatalogs;  // gets list of databases
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.BackupDB(const DBName: String);
var
  FileName,
  Sql : String;
begin
  FileName := scBackUpPath + DBName + scBackUpExtn;
  Sql := 'backup database %s to disk = ''%s''';
  Sql := Format(Sql, [DBName, FileName]);
  Log('Backing up ' + DBName + ' using SQL: ' + Sql);
  try
    Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
    Update;
    FDConnection1.ExecSQL(Sql);
    Log('Done');
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnBackUpClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BackUpDB(DatabaseName);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnRestoreClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RestoreDB(DatabaseName);
end;

procedure TForm1.RestoreDB(const DBName: String);
var
  FileName,
  Sql : String;
begin
  FileName := scBackUpPath + DBName + scBackUpExtn;
  if FileExists(FileName) then begin
    //  Note:  beware the 'with replace' in the following
    Sql := 'restore database %s from disk = ''%s'' with replace';
    Sql := Format(Sql, [DBName, FileName]);
    Log('Restoring ' + DBName + ' using SQL: ' + Sql);
    try
      Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
      Update;
      FDConnection1.ExecSQL(Sql);
      Log('Done');
    finally
      Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    end;
  end
  else
    Log('Backup file ' + FileName + ' not found!');
end;
```

Obviously that's a bit light on error-checking, but i'm sure you'll get the idea.

Before it was phased out I'd use Delphi automation to SqlServer's Sql-DMO library to
do this because it was easy to implement progress callbacks like "% completed".

I haven't managed to do anything useful yet with Sql_DOM's successor, SMO, from Delphi
and these days I'd do this using a TADOConnection rather than FireDAC if only
because there's less baggage involved in getting the list of databases and the
ADO Errors collection provides an easy way of getting at any errors encountered.

Comment: This seems to work well.  I can probably live without progress as the databases are relatively small (under 100MB) so should backup and restore quickly.

Comment: _"I have managed to do anything useful yet with Sql_DOM's successor, SMO, from Delphi"_, SMO is for .NET only, so you would have to write a wrapper for it. Though it's a good tip!

Comment: @Victoria.  Thanks, I was aware of the need for a wrapper for SMO, so have haven't bothered to do anything about it.  The only reason I used DMO previously was the ease with which one can get progress callbacks on lengthy operations, and I didn't fancy jumping through hoops to get SMO working only to find some show-stopping problem with them.